# I can't see what I need in order to post a comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, popup

[image]

I can't see what I need to comment.
There is just a blank space. Here is a larger version of the problem

[image: Blank space]

Comment: To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) (50 rep points) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @jonrsharpe not really. This question is about a bug, the popup is there but doesn't display "50 reputation".

Comment: @CodeCaster oh, I see, I thought the OP just wanted to know why they couldn't comment

Comment: Obviously the blank space in that popup means that you need an open mind in order to be able to comment.

Comment: If you look closer at the image you can see the "50 Reputation" although it blends in with the popup's background.

Comment: He he he :) "You must have to comment". Yeah that needs a fix: if it is doubly urgent then it should read "you must have to comment!"

Comment: You must have *insert pun here* to comment

Comment: You must have not been able to comment.

Comment: Yay for _testing_

Comment: You must have the eyes of a falcon to see that you need 50 rep to comment.

Comment: Confirmed, I created a new test account and tried to comment: http://puu.sh/kBPvx/5a9cd88ba4.png.

Comment: You must have to meta stack overflow

Comment: Temporary work around: You can override the the color for links in your browser.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Fixed now.

This innocent-looking selector made it into our CSS:

```
a:not(.badge-tag, .post-tag) {
```

– unfortunately, that syntax is illegal in CSS3. It will be legal in CSS4, but there's not a single browser that supports it yet. Fortunately it has an easy CSS3 equivalent:

```
a:not(.badge-tag):not(.post-tag) {
```

That's what's in the CSS now, and the link is readable again.

Answer (score 93):

If we look really close we can see it says "50 reputation" in the blank spot.

[image]

And if we put it into paint and use a fill with color using white we get:

[image]

So the text is there but the color styling for the link is making it blend in.  They need to fix the CSS for the popup.

Another thing that could be done is the popup could be made red like other error popups as it is an error and then the blue link would stand out against the red background.

Comment: *They need to fix the CSS* or we need to get a pair of "Ninja Eyes" ;)

Comment: @BhargavRao Keep reading grayed out post and you will develop "Ninja Eyes"

Comment: This is a test right? I'm on candid camera now? You're kidding me....

Comment: That's some real NCIS stuff you just did there: zoom and enhance.

Comment: @gunr2171 What can I say.  I grew up watching CSI.

Comment: it made me to clean my screen !!!

Comment: [You can do some funky things with colors and values too](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UuHF8.png)

Comment: Now do a Bones version and create a 3D hologram rendering which you can completely reprogram with a few taps on a tablet.

Comment: @Gimby The images are already in 4D.  Do you not have a 4D compliant video card/monitor?

Comment: Yes but my glasses broke :(